upper limit for sampling frequency
I have a signal $s(t)$. The sampling frequency at least at twice the largest frequency ($f_s \geq 2f_{max}$).
Here is my question: is there an upper limit to the choice of sampling frequency? For example can I take $f_s=10^6 f_{max}$?

You can "take"the sampling frequency to be $10^6 f_\max$ or $10^{\text{one gazillion}}f_\max$ or any other multiple of $f_\max$ if you like; whether hardware exists that can actually sample at that frequency (and return a reasonably accurate sample value while doing so), and whether hardware/DSP processors exist that can process the sample values at that high rate, are issues that you might also wish to think about.

While there is no theoretical upper bound, there definitely is a practical one. As @DilipSarwate mentions, you would need to have hardware that can sample and process at that high of a rate. Additionally, your frequency resolution in DFT land is $\frac{f_{s}}{N}$. If you scale $f_{s}$ by $10^{6}$, you would have to scale $N$ by $10^{6}$ to achieve equivalent frequency resolution for processing spectra. The amount of operations to compute spectra will quickly grow as FFTs are $\mathcal{O}\left(N\log N\right)$

Note that fs > 2fmax is the requirement, not fs >= 2fmax


Here is my question: is there an upper limit to the choice of sampling frequency?

Not in terms of data integrity or fundamental math. The desire too keep the sample rate as low as possible is simply a practical one: Pretty much all things DSP get more expensive (in terms of CPU, power, parts, cost, signal to noise ratio) as the sample rate increases.
Another concern is noise: by choosing a higher sample rate you extend the bandwidth to frequencies you don't need. Turns out, there is always SOME amount energy at these frequencies and sometimes that energy can interfere with what you want to do.  There are example of "high res" audio tracks, that are actually worse than the "CD quality track" since some extraneous noise has somehow made into the frequency range above 20 kHz.

For example can I take $f_s=10^6 f_{max}$?

You'd be very hard pressed to find a ADC converters that would support that sample rate for any "normal" communications system.

Could you elaborate "there is always SOME amount energy at these frequencies and sometimes that energy can interfere with what you want to do"? How the energy interfere with the signal of interest? If hardware imperfection, could you please name it? Thanks.

@AlexTP: Here is an example: I analyzed a specific audio recording (Billboard top 100) and found a huge noise spike above 20 kHz. That prematurely triggered a limiter and also was a risk of  physically damaging a tweeter. I talked the engineer who mastered the recording and it was clearly an accident. I you have noise you can hear, you deal with it. If you have noise you can't hear, it slips through the cracks.
